# after_update doesn't fire

Tags: 6, hooks

I don't know what the problem is, but why don't after_update fire? I can replace it with insert and it works but this doesn't for some reason.

```
function maillist_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL){
    if($op == 'after_update'){
        maillist_register_submit(); 
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is as soon as a new user is registered to my site I want to use that uid but I can't figure out how to get that uid.

Answer (score 1):

The **after_update** case called is called after the user modifies his account from my understanding of [hook_user](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_user/6).

So that would mean that the user account has been created and the user updates his profile such as changing user image or password etc., which would trigger **update** and `after_update`.

I guess when the user is created it is only normal that the insert is triggered. If you have customized the registration so that in course of the registration the user account has been created and while completion the account information is being modified by him the update and after_update would be triggered.

If you wish to get the uid of the user who's registered most recently I suggest you could implement `hook_user` with insert case and query the database to get the max(uid) which would be the recently added user's id, only making sure your module has a greater weight so that user module's insert of the user happens first and your retrieval of the uid follows it. Though my suggestion feels less than optimal I believe it would work.

Comment: As per the [doc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/6), user_save returns a full `$user` object, including the newly created `$user->uid`.